# Move first "n" files sorted by name with Bash Script or Ubuntu command line

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I need a command line or a bash script to move the first 80 files (name sorted) in a folder (which contains 30000 files) into new folders which will store this chunk of 80 files for individual processing with Imagemagick.
I have tried with `ls pathtofolder/Pictures/* | head -80 | xargs -I{} cp {} pathtofolder/OutputFolder` and other similar codes but the files (named by `Pictures%d.jpg`) are copied in weird orders (like 1 to 5, then 10 to 16, then 100 to 160, and so on, completing 80 files in total).

The easiest way I found was with the use of `convert image-%d.jpg[1-5]`, as says [this page](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php), but It seems that it doesn't work (I tried with `convert -delay 3.33 -loop 0 pathtofolder/Pictures%d.jpg[100-180] pathtofolder/Test.gif`), throws this error:

> zsh: no matches found:
>   /home/naldrek/Videos/Pictures/Pictures%d.jpg[100-180]

I tried other things too, and I read a lot over the internet. Can't make it work.

Comment: If the files are named with 1..9, 10..99, 100..999, etc., try "ls -v" to sort them numerically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about straightforward solution like

```
for F in $(ls -U | sort | head -80); do 
    cp $F /path/to/target
    convert /path/to/target/$F
done
```